# Display a countdown

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I need a timer implemented in my application, which will do a countdown from 10 sec - 0 sec.
and, display the countdown in a `JLabel`.

Here's my implementation;

```
...
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new List());
        t.start();

}

class List implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int sec = 0;
        label.setText(""+sec);
        // Do a if- condition check to see if the clock has reached to, and then stop

    }

}
```

I was expecting the JLabel to start counting from 0 - 10 and then stop. But it doesn't. The JLabel set the value `0` and it doesn't get incremented.

UPDATE 1

```
    t = new Timer(1000, new Listner());
    t.start();


}

class Listner implements ActionListener{
    private int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lable.setText(""+ (counter++));

        if (counter == 10)
              t.removeActionListener(this);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not storing nor incrementing `secs` anywhere so I don't see how it should get updated, try with

```
Timer timer;

void start() {
  timer = new Timer(1000,new List());
}

class List implements ActionListener {
    private counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText(""+counter++);

        if (counter == 10)
          timer.removeActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

Mind that you need to store a reference to the timer somewhere to be able to remove the listener from it once countdown finished.

Comment: wont the counter start from 0 each time the actionPerformed is called?

Comment: @Fyre No. `private counter = 0;` is created when the class is created.  In `actionPerformed` the `counter` is just incremented.

Comment: So is it `private` int `counter=0` ? I made that change, but it still doesn't get incremented. I see the text `9`. and it doesn't get incremented or decremented.

Comment: But did you change the code inside actionPerformed to use `counter` instead that your local variable?

Comment: I updated my post, with the code. I don't see the counter increment. Help

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaach not `timer.removeActionListener(this);` but `timer.stop(:-)` please

Comment: @mKorbel: it actually depends on how many tasks you have on it.

Comment: @Jack whaaaaaaat :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Well each time the timer is called it declares the int variable sec to 0. Hence the Label doesnt get updated.

You should declare the sec variable as a global variable and then in the actionPerformed method increment its value each time it is called.

```
 public int sec = 0;
 class List implements ActionListener{

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sec++;
        label.setText(""+sec);
        // Do a if- condition check to see if the clock has reached to, and then stop

  }

}
```

Comment: I recommend swap the order & make `sec` an attribute of the listener class. E.G.  `class List implements ActionListener{  private int sec = 0; ..`

Comment: The counter doesn't start from `0`. instead it starts from `8` and then ends at 9. This is because i am stopping the timer at `10`

Answer (score 3):

A complete example

```
public class ATimerExample {

    Timer timer;
    int counter = 0;

    public ATimerExample() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("somethgi");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("0");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                counter++;
                if (counter == 10) {
                    //timer.removeActionListener(this);
                      timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ATimerExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since java reads the time in milliseconds, it should be 10000 instead of 1000. try your code and see if that works. I had the same problem when I wanted 30 seconds. And instead of writing Timer t = new Timer(30000, new List());       t.start();

I wrote Timer t = new Timer(3000, new List());
        t.start();

That made my program to stop every after 3 seconds. I would suggest, you use 10000 instead of 1000.

Remember to do: t.stop() in your List class. Thanks